# Custom vector class template failing initializer

Tags: c++, class, templates, vector

I am doing a project for class and I think I have led myself into confusion following the book.

We are building a custom vector class with templates, which will go through a series of tests.

With my current code, it is failing when initializing the following statement.

```
Vector<int> v {1,2,3};
```

Here are my files.

vector.hpp

```
#ifndef VECTOR_HPP
#define VECTOR_HPP

#include <memory>

template<typename T, typename A = std::allocator<T> >
struct Vector_base {
    A alloc;
    T* elem;
    T* space;
    T* last;

    Vector_base(const A& a, typename A::size_type n) : alloc{a}, elem{alloc.allocate(n)}, space{elem+n}, last{elem+n} { }
    ~Vector_base() { alloc.deallocate(elem,last-elem); }
    Vector_base(const Vector_base&) = delete;

    Vector_base& operator=(const Vector_base&) = delete;
    Vector_base(Vector_base&&);
    Vector_base& operator=(Vector_base&&);
};

template<typename T, typename A = std::allocator<T> >
class Vector {
    Vector_base<T,A> vb;
    void destroy_elements();
public:
    using size_type = typename A::size_type;

    bool is_empty() const
    {
        return this->empty();
    }

    explicit Vector(size_type n, const T& val = T(), const A& = A());

    Vector() {}

    Vector(const Vector& a);
    Vector& operator=(const Vector& a);

    Vector(Vector&& a);
    Vector& operator=(Vector&& a);

    ~Vector() { destroy_elements(); }

    size_type size() const { return vb.space-vb.elem; }
    size_type capacity() const { return vb.last-vb.elem; }

    void reserve(size_type);

    void resize(size_type, const T& = {});
    void clear() { resize(0); }
    void push_back(const T&); 
};

#endif
```

vector.cpp

```
#include "vector.hpp"
#include <memory>

//template<typename T, typename A>
Vector_base<T,A>::Vector_base(Vector_base&& a) : alloc{a.alloc}, elem{a.elem}, space{a.space}, last{a.space}
{
    a.elem = a.space = a.last = nullptr;
}

//template<typename T, typename A>
Vector_base<T,A>& Vector_base<T,A>::operator=(Vector_base&& a)
{
    swap(*this,a);
    return *this;
}

//template<typename T, typename A>
void Vector<T,A>::destroy_elements()
{
    for (T* p = vb.elem; p!=vb.space; ++p)
        p-> ~T();

    vb.space=vb.elem;
}

//template<typename For, typename T>
void uninitialized_fill(For beg, For end, const T& x)
{
    For p;
    try {
        for (p=beg; p!=end; ++p)
            ::new(static_cast<void*>(&*p)) T(x);
    }
    catch (...) {
        for (For q = beg; q!=p; ++q)
            (&*q)-> ~T();
        throw;
    }
}

//template<typename T, typename A>
Vector<T,A>::Vector(size_type n, const T& val, const A& a) : vb{a,n}
{
    uninitialized_fill(vb.elem,vb.elem+n,val);
}


//template<typename T, typename A>
Vector<T,A>::Vector(const Vector<T,A>& a) : vb{a.alloc,a.size()}
{
    std::uninitialized_copy(a.begin(),a.end(),vb.elem);
}

//template<typename T, typename A>
Vector<T,A>::Vector(Vector<T,A>&& a) : vb{move(a.vb)} { }

/*template<typename T, typename A>
Vector<T,A>::Vector(const Vector& a)
{

}*/

//template<typename T, typename A>
Vector<T,A>& Vector<T,A>::operator=(Vector<T,A>&& a)
{
    clear();
    swap(vb,a.vb);
    return *this;
}

//template<typename T, typename A>
Vector<T,A>& Vector<T,A>::operator=(const Vector& a)
{
    if(capacity() < a.size())
    {
        Vector temp {a};
        swap(*this,temp);
        return *this;
    }

    if (this == &a) { return *this; }

    size_type sz = size();
    size_type asz = a.size();
    vb.alloc = a.vb.alloc;
    if (asz<=sz) 
    {
        copy(a.begin(),a.begin()+sz,vb.elem);
        for(T* p = vb.elem+asz; p!=vb.space; ++p)
            p-> ~T();
    }
    else
    {
        copy(a.begin(),a.begin()+sz,vb.elem);
        uninitialized_copy(a.begin()+sz,a.end(),vb.space);
    }
    vb.space = vb.elem+asz;
    return *this;
}

//template<typename T, typename A>
void safe_assign(Vector<T,A>& a, Vector<T,A> b)
{
    swap(a,b);
}

//template<typename T, typename A>
void Vector<T,A>::reserve(size_type newalloc)
{
    if (newalloc<=capacity()) return;
    Vector_base<T,A> b {vb.alloc,newalloc-size()};
    uninitialized_move(vb.elem,vb.elem+size(),b.elem);
    swap(vb,b);
}

//template<typename In, typename Out>
Out uninitialized_move(In b, In e, Out oo)
{
    using T = typename std::iterator_traits<Out>::value_type;
    for (; b!=e; ++b,++oo) {
        new(static_cast<void*>(&*oo)) T{move(*b)};
        b-> ~T();
    }
    return oo;
}

//template<typename T, typename A>
void Vector<T,A>::resize(size_type newsize, const T& val)
{
    reserve(newsize);
    if (size()<newsize)
        uninitialized_fill(vb.elem+size(),vb.elem+newsize,val);
    else
        destroy(vb.elem+newsize,vb.elem+size());
    vb.space = vb.elem+newsize;
}

//template<typename In>
void destroy(In b, In e)
{
    using T = typename std::iterator_traits<In>::value_type;
    for (; b!=e; ++b)
        b-> ~T();
}

//template<typename T, typename A>
void Vector<T,A>::push_back(const T& val)
{
    if (capacity()==size())
        reserve(size()?2*size():8);
    vb.alloc.construct(&vb.elem[size()],val);
    ++vb.space;
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You need a constructor taking [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list). Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/1782465

Comment: @Clix Why have you commented out `template` lines? And are you expecting `{1,2,3}` to call `Vector(size_type n, const T& val, const A&)` overload?

Comment: @LogicStuff I forgot I still had them commented. Someone on another board suggested that templates were not allowed in anything expect header files.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. But the solution is to move the whole definitions (with `template` prefixes) to the header file. There's no other way.

Comment: I did end up moving them. I still receive the same error as before. I believe the problem is what Angew suggested; although, I am not quite sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge all template code has to be in headers, because the actual implementation is done by the compiler. The reason the initialization fails is that the compiler cannot find the definition for your functions.

Move all your code into `vector.hpp`.

*Edit: Also, you need a constructor that takes `initializer_list` as an argument.*

Comment: This might not be worth being an answer, but I can't comment yet.